# What's the proper constant naming convention for words stylized in CamelCase?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, constants, camelcasing

Everyone knows that Java's constant naming convention is uppercase with underscores between words, like `USERNAME` and `ERROR_CODE`.
But should words/names that are normally spelled in CamelCase also use an underscore? Should SomeBrand™ be named `SOME_BRAND` or `SOMEBRAND`? The latter can be harder to read and it doesn't convey the proper case, but the former can be incorrectly read as separate words, especially with another word attached (e.g. `SOME_BRAND_ID`). Is there an accepted convention? Maybe a third option?

Comment: `MCDONALDS` or `MC_DONALDS` - I'd say the latter holds to convention better and is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would use `SOMEBRAND`. One reason is the same that jonmecer mentioned, because SomeBrand is treated as one word in a sentence. In addition, `SOME_BRAND` could lead to confusion about its definition: do you mean you are talking about "some brand", or are you talking about your one and only SomeBrand™? Putting it as `SOMEBRAND` clears up any confusion in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

According to [sun](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html) each word should be separated by "_". Now when you type **SomeBrand** in a sentence, you would treat it as a word. So, I think `SOMEBRAND` works better. But then again, this is based on your company's policy.